# No networks: showing in WIFI in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, tp-link

I am using AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 20.04.

I have used following commands to install the driver:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
```

The output of iwconfig is :

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

��$�"E    unassociated  ESSID:""  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

nmcli device is giving this output :

```
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION         
eno1             ethernet  connected    Wired connection 1 
\264\260$\277"E  wifi      unavailable  --                 
lo               loopback  unmanaged    --
```

output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:011e TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This was working before but then I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 from a bootable usb. After that it started giving me this error.

I don't know why name of 3rd interface in iwconfig is coming like this(I think this might be the issue), I tried installing the drivers for AC600 multiple time but every time facing same issue.

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe -r 88XXau` and then: `sudo modprobe 88XXau ifname=wlan0` and tell us if there is any improvement. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I tried using `sudo modprobe -r 88XXau` and then: `sudo modprobe 88XXau ifname=wlan0` but there are no improvements.

Comment: Before I propose an answer, may we identify your exact device? `lsusb`

Comment: This one is the exact device:  `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:011e TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem, a weird interface name, is the subject of a very recent Issue at the github repository: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/issues/969

I assume that the suggested solution will be soon be corrected in the code, however, let’s implement it now. First, remove the current driver:

```
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_remove
```

Now let’s revise the code as suggested in the issue at github:

```
nano include/drv_types_linux.h
```

Change the line:

```
#define dev_addr_set(netdev, ethdata) _rtw_memcpy(netdev, ethdata, ETH_ALEN)
```

To read:

```
#define dev_addr_set(netdev, ethdata) _rtw_memcpy(netdev->dev_addr, ethdata, ETH_ALEN)
```

Proofread very carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit the text editor (Ctrl+x).

Now let’s install the revised driver:

```
sudo make dkms_install
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.