# Wifi adapter is unavailable in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, wireless, network-manager

I just bought a wifi adapter TP-Link AC 600 and installed those kernel modules
`$ dkms status`

```
8812au, 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 5.4.0-122-generic, x86_64: installed
broadcom-sta, 6.30.223.271, 5.4.0-122-generic, x86_64: installed
```

but when I tried to use in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS NetworkManager shows it is unavailable:

`$ nmcli d`

```
DEVICE              TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION          
wlp6s0              wifi      connected    <My Wifi Network>  
\264\260$k\035\362  wifi      unavailable  --                  
docker0             bridge    unmanaged    --                  
enp7s0              ethernet  unmanaged    --                  
lo                  loopback  unmanaged    --                  
p2p-dev-wlp6s0      wifi-p2p  unmanaged    --
```

`rfkill` says it is unblocked

`$ rfkill`

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy1   unblocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

I can see it is the second device. And als

`$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k, wl
```

I believe wl should be in use.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT1:

This is the `lsusb` output

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0cf3:0036 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:670b Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:011e TP-Link 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: *wl* is a driver for Broadcom devices and you have none. Please remove it: `sudo apt purge broadcom-sta-dkms` As for the interface with the weird name, please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418771/no-networks-showing-in-wifi-in-ubuntu-20-04/1418913#1418913  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for  `lsusb` if you used the aircrack-ng rtl8812au driver from github, there is an issue

Comment: "2357:011e TP-Link" So did you install the driver from aircrack-ng? If so, follow the link I gave above.

Comment: Thank you chili555, I remove Broadcomdriver and followed the instructions of the question but did not resolve the interface name neither the unavailable status.

Comment: Yes, I realize I forgot to say in the question I installed the aircrack driver in github https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git