# Wifi adapter not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, wireless, network-manager

I just bought a wifi adapter TP-Link AC 600 and installed this driver from github repository https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git.

but when I tried to use in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS NetworkManager shows it is unavailable:

`$ nmcli d`

```
DEVICE              TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION          
wlp6s0              wifi      connected    <My Wifi Network>  
\264\260$k\035\362  wifi      unavailable  --                  
docker0             bridge    unmanaged    --                  
enp7s0              ethernet  unmanaged    --                  
lo                  loopback  unmanaged    --                  
p2p-dev-wlp6s0      wifi-p2p  unmanaged    --
```

I found that there is a bug in this driver and followed the instructions of this question [No networks: showing in WIFI in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418771/no-networks-showing-in-wifi-in-ubuntu-20-04/1418913#1418913), but did not change anything. Also

`$ dkms status`

```
8812au, 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 5.4.0-122-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

And `rfkill` says it is unblocked

`$ rfkill`

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy1   unblocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

I can see it is the second device. And also

`$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

This is the `lsusb` output

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:0036 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:670b Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2357:011e TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I asked a question before [Wifi adapter is unavailable in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419196/wifi-adapter-is-unavailable-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts) and the only difference now is the name that appears in `lsusb`.

EDIT1:
Here is what I changed in include/drv_types_linux.h

before change

```
#ifndef __DRV_TYPES_LINUX_H__
#define __DRV_TYPES_LINUX_H__

#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5, 15, 0))
#define dev_addr_set(netdev, ethdata) _rtw_memcpy(netdev, ethdata, ETH_ALEN) 
#endif

#endif
```

after change

```
#ifndef __DRV_TYPES_LINUX_H__
#define __DRV_TYPES_LINUX_H__

#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5, 15, 0))
#define dev_addr_set(netdev, ethdata) _rtw_memcpy(netdev->dev_addr, ethdata, ETH_ALEN) 
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of the include/drv_types_linux.h file that you amended.

Comment: I might be wrong since i am a linux newbie myself, but do you have the Linux-modules-extra package installed?
you can check that using: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` If it's missing, try installing that package and see if that solves your problem, it solved mine when i was trying to make the Mediatek MT7601U adapter work on ubuntu on my raspberry pi 4

Comment: Yes is installed `Status: install ok installed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a different driver. First, remove the aircrack-ng version:

```
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_remove
```

Next, with a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708.git
cd 8821au-20210708
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Thank you chili555, now it's fixed, the interface name is not weird as well.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.